# What is the difference between chunk and pagination in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, chunking

I already read some article but I am still confused.
I n pagination it will execute a query when load a page but what happen in **chunk** ?
I read https://laravel-school.com/posts/laravel-pagination-vs-chunk-51 this article and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now pagination works on a per page basis. So if you for example have 100 records and you retrieve 10 records per page you need to perform 10 queries to get all results. However since it's pagination you have a page number you use to determine which records you will return. For example page 3 will return the records 21-30 and so on. Here you will always only load 10 records in memory and return them. Query wise this works with a limit and offset to determine the correct records.

Now looking at chunk it's actually a bit different. So if we still take the 100 records and we chunk them by 10 records we still parse all the 100 records. However it will only load 10 records in memory at a time. So it's using a similar query approach using limit and offset, however it will eventually return all results, but in batches/chunks instead of only return 1 set of records.

The documentation also does a good job of explaining this: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#chunking-results

Comment: Can you please elaborate this
 "Now looking at chunk it's actually a bit different. So if we still take the 100 records and we chunk them by 10 records we still parse all the 100 records." ?

Comment: What dont you understand? If you have 100 records you will parse all of them but only show 10. And if you paginate you will only parse 10.

Comment: Is chunk retrieve all 100 records from database at a time ?

Comment: Yes it will return all 100, but load show only 10 at a time.

Comment: If I have 1 million data & I use chunk in that case it will take lots of time to retrieve all data at a time. So in this scenario what will I do? Is chunk help in this scenario ?

Comment: If you want to display the data in a view use paginate, if you want to take data and do something with it like update each row then use chunk.

Comment: Now I am clear about it.
Great !